# Need to convert a String to a Intent that I can send?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

What code do i need on the receiving end of my broadcast receiver to convert a string into a working intent I can send? So in short I need intent1 to converted to a working intent which I can send! Thanks in advance everyone!

**EDIT**
So I came to find out that my method of storing the Notification Intent didn't work so I guess my main question at this point is how can I get the notifications Intent and send that over the Broadcast Sender and receive that Intent in the Broadcast receiver and then being able to send that intent...Thanks for bearing with me I'm very confused on how to make this happen so thank you to this community for helping me out

Broadcast Sender

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {


    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    String title = extras.getString("android.title");
    String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("action", notification.contentIntent);

    Log.i("Package", pack);
    Log.i("Ticker", ticker);
    Log.i("Title",title);
    Log.i("Text", text);

    Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
    msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
    msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
    msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
    msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);


    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
            String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
            int seconds = Integer.parseInt(duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`intent.getParcelableExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String))

```
Intent intent1 = intent.getParcelableExtra("action");
```

Comment: Hey I don't know if you saw my update or not but basically what I was trying to do didn't work. So i was wondering if you have any idea on how to write the code correctly to be able to send an Intent over a broadcast sender and then receiving it.

Comment: @SkylerMartin Why would this not work? `Intent` is parcelable, you can put parcelable extras on an intent and get them wherever the intent is received. As of now, your question has not changed and there is no new information that suggests this won't work (except that you are no longer putting the extra on the `msgrcv` intent that you are broadcasting). Perhaps you should elaborate your question; i see 3 intents but don't know what they are all meant for, except the one you are broadcasting to yourself.

Comment: I get this error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.PendingIntent.send()' on a null object reference

Comment: @SkylerMartin If the code above is the most recent, then you aren't adding the intent as an extra on `msgrcv` (the Intent you are broadcasting to yourself). I see you've created another Intent (named `intent` above) and given that an extra named "action", but I don't see this intent being used anywhere. Make sure *the Intent you are broadcasting* has the extra; if that doesn't solve your problem, then update (or at least clarify) your code above as it that is the only information we have to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
String pack=sbn.getPackageName();
String ticker=sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
Bundle extras=sbn.getNotification().extras;
String title=extras.getString("android.title");
String text=extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

Log.i("Package", pack);
Log.i("Ticker", ticker);
Log.i("Title",title);
Log.i("Text", text);
Intent msgrcv = new Intent();
msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
msgrcv.setAction ("myapp.broadcast.notification");
context.sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(duration);
```

And **make sure** that your intent filters **`<action/>`** is set to 
`<action android:name="myapp.broadcast.notification"/>`

Comment: that code should work great but what code do I need in my onReceive code to get the intent? And when you say that I need to have that Intent filter does that need to go in the Service class or the Main Activity Class? Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Just put the code I put under the Title Broadcast Receiver inside the broadcast receiver class. As for the action tag. In your Manifest file where you have declared a broadcast receiver I presume add under intent filter add <action android:name="myapp.broadcast.notification"/>

Comment: If you have declared them programmatically or if you have not declared it at all do let me know. And also tell me the name of your broadcast receiver.